# Why are 404s not triggering my 404.php template?

Tags: templates, 404-error

404s are not triggering my 404.php template. The header status code, checked in firebug, is a 404, but the page that gets displayed is like a loop with 0 items (as if this were simply an archive page with 0 entries).

If my permalinks start with /%year%/ and I go to bla.com/9999 (which should produce a 404), WP Debug shows the request as a year:

```
Request: 9999
Query String: year=9999
Matched Rewrite Rule: ([0-9]{4})/?$
Matched Rewrite Query: year=9999
```

If my permalinks start with /%category%/ and I go to bla.com/zzzzz (which should produce a 404), WP Debug shows the request as a category_name:

```
Request: zzzzz
Query String: category_name=zzzzz
Matched Rewrite Rule: (.+?)/?$
Matched Rewrite Query: category_name=zzzzz
```

What's going on? The Show Template plugin (which prints an html comment telling you what template was used to render the page) tells me that the page is rendering with the index.php template. How can I get my 404.php template to load?

Comment: This seems like something that extension code might break. Disable all plugins, switch to default theme and check if that makes a difference.

Comment: Changing to another theme eliminates the problem, but what sort of thing should I be looking for in my original thing to fix this? I built it, based on the Boilerplate theme, and I don't have very many actions hooked into the header.

Comment: Sorry I do not have a good guess. Just try same approach with theme - remove hooked stuff to nothing and if it helps add back piece by piece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the problem was with the otherwise very useful plugin [Legacy URL Forwarding](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/url-forwarding/).

It uses the following function (abridged here) with the `404_template` hook.

```
function doUrlForwarding() {

// make a $query based on the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

// if a post is found, redirect to it
   if (!empty($query->post->ID)) {
      wp_redirect(get_permalink($query->post->ID), '301' );
   }
}

add_action('404_template','doUrlForwarding');
```

With the above hook active, the 404.php does not get fired. However, if I place `doUrlForwarding` at the top of 404.php, it works correctly.

> This answers the mystery, but I still don't know why using the
>   404_template hook is preventing the 404.php template from loading on
>   normal 404s. Comment if you have an idea.